# Raphael, after assigning data, i am not able to get it

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am assigning the data value through loop, but while i check the element for each, no attributes are find... any one correct my function?

```
var paper = new Raphael('slideContainer', 930, 420);

    //mainpage circles;-
var mainPageCircle = {
    circles :{
        cR:{color:'#730000',text:'Content'},
        cB:{color:'#004f74',text:'Consulting'},
        cG:{color:'#146c00',text:'Commerce'}
    },
    radious:100,
    stroke:10,
    strokeColor:'#fff',
    opacity:0.7
}


 $.each(mainCrProp.circles, function (n) {
        pCircles =  paper.circle(
                                     n==='cR' ? (paperWidth/2) - mainCrProp.radious/2 :
                                     n==='cB' ? paper.getById('cR').attr('cx') + mainCrProp.radious : (paperWidth/2),
                                     n==='cR' ? (paperHeight/2) - mainCrProp.radious/2 :
                                     n==='cB' ? paper.getById('cR').attr('cy') : 
                                     n==='cG' ? paper.getById('cR').attr('cy') + mainCrProp.radious : paperHeight/2,
                                     mainCrProp.radious)
        .attr({fill:this.color,'stroke-width':mainCrProp.stroke,stroke:mainCrProp.strokeColor,opacity:mainCrProp.opacity})
        .data('dClass',(i+'Group'))//i am setting my data..
        .id = n;
        //
        pText = paper.text(          n==='cR' ? (paperWidth/2) - mainCrProp.radious:
                                     n==='cB' ? paper.getById('cR').attr('cx') + mainCrProp.radious*1.5 : (paperWidth/2),
                                     n==='cR' ? (paperHeight/2) - mainCrProp.radious/2 :
                                     n==='cB' ? paper.getById('cR').attr('cy') : 
                                     n==='cG' ? paper.getById('cR').attr('cy') + mainCrProp.radious*1.5 : paperHeight/2,
                                     this.text)
        .data('dClass',(i+'Group'))//i am setting my data
        .id = n+'text';
        pGroup[i] = paper.set(pCircles,pText);
        i++;
    } )

    paper.forEach(function (el) {
        console.log(el.data('dClass'));// i  am not getting any data value..    
    } )
```

[Sample work is here](http://jsfiddle.net/h6U87/)

Comment: Can you do console.log(el) and get the element?

Comment: yes, i am getting elements.even i am getting id's

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle.net to show an example so we can play around?

Comment: can you play there in my jsfiddle? i added the comments. i need to know how to add the data, and id in single object.

Comment: the reason is, i just want to add some event in the id's. as well using their data(no.of objects) i will do some animation.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Ok firstly the `id` is provided for you by `Raphael` so don't overwrite that. This is why you are losing your `data` I think, have a look at this example of reading the `id` and also setting some `user data`:

```
var paper = new Raphael('container',500,500);

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
paper.circle(10 + 25 * i, 10, 10)
     .attr({fill: "#000"})
    .data("myData", {customId: "customId:" + i})
     .click(function () {
        console.log(this.data("myData").customId);
 });
}
```

Example here - http://jsfiddle.net/h6U87/3/

Comment: I agree with you. but i required the custom Id's.

Comment: Because generally the Raphael it self assigning the id's as number. that is very tough to find the elements.

Comment: I've edited my answer again, just use an object in the data and add a customId to that, you can put whatever you like in it.