# Raphael not adding an id nor data attribute

Tags: svg, raphael

Hopefully someone has an answer because looking at the example code in the documentation and the 'Free Icons' script I just can't see how this isn't working.

My issue is I am trying to create a beanie (hat).  This beanie is made up of a number of different sections which I have stored in a variable named 'beanie' like so:

```
beanie = {
  section1: "PATH CO-ORDINATES",
  section2: "PATH CO-ORDINATES",
  section3: "PATH CO-ORDINATES"
};
```

Basically the same way the 'Free Icons' are done as mentioned previously.  I have then looped through all sections and created each on the paper like so:

```
for (var section in beanie) {
  activeSection = beanieWindow.path(beanie[section]).attr({
    'fill': '#ffffff',
    'stroke': 'none'
  })
  .data('section', beanie[section])
  .click(function () {
    makeActiveSection(this);
  })
  .hover(
    function () {
      this.attr('stroke', 'red');
    },
    function () {
      this.attr('stroke', 'none');
    }
  );
}
```

This this all works wonderfully, but when inspecting the paths there is no data-section attribute added - not even an 'id' attribute, which Neil mentions in his answer on [Raphael, after assigning data, i am not able to get it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249681/raphael-after-assigning-data-i-am-not-able-to-get-it) that the id is provided by Raphael.

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but if I am I just can't see it :-/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Mat

Comment: What is the question and what are you trying to do ? The `data` is not pushed to the DOM, it's only available as a property on the javascript object. You should be able to access `this.data` in your click event handler for example.

Comment: Thanks this was what I was after - much appreciated!